# Issue with 'Promise<QueryResult<any>>' for TypeScript + Postgres API

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, express

I'm creating an API with TypeScript and Postgres but I'm having an issue with my 'response' on line 6. I'm unclear how the promise is working here and how to resolve this. Am I missing an interface or type constructor? Doesn't seem like it's needed here..

From the error message it seems like I'm missing an 'any' type (which doesn't solve the problem) and defeats the purpose of using TS.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

The error message is:

```
Type 'Promise<QueryResult<any>>' is missing the following properties from type 'QueryResult<any>': rows, command, rowCount, oid, fields ts(2739)

const response: QueryResult<any>
```

The code which has the error is as follows:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { QueryResult } from 'pg';
import { pool } from '../database';

export const getUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
 const response: QueryResult = pool.query('SELECT * FROM users');
 console.log(response.rows);
 res.send('users');
};
```

Comment: What does pool.query returns? Can you add pool.query?

Comment: turns out I forgot an 'await' before the pool.query as it's a promise